# how to create multiple drop down list items in asp.net with angular Js

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, vb.net

Now i am creating a simple student registration form. Now i have two drop down list box in my form.

First Box is Contains, Gender Details and the second one contains subject details.

Now i am trying to populate these items for the corresponding list boxes in my application using angular Js.

But i failed and also i am beginner for the angular js. Some one please guide me. 
I put my codes here.

```
<div class="stud details" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

     Gender:<select>
            <option ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</option>
        </select>


    Subject:<select ng-model="selectedUom">
        <option ng-repeat="x in sub" value="{{x.sub}}">{{x.sub}}</option>
        </select>

</div>


 <script>
       var app = angular.module("myapp", [])
     app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
         $scope.names = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'Male' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Female' }, 
         { Id: 3, Name: 'Others' }];
         });
     app.controller('MyController', function ($Scope) {
         $Scope.sub = [{ id: 1, uom: 'Tam' }, { id: 2, uom: 'Eng' }, { id: 
    3, uom: 'Math' }, { id: 4, uom: 'Science' }];
     });

  </script>
```

Actually my drop down list box are show a empty set of list items on run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected something for you. But i don't know what you want exactly. You need to check this below snippet code for what you missed.

```js
       var app = angular.module("myapp", [])
     app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
         $scope.names = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'Male' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Female' }, 
                         { Id: 3, Name: 'Others' }];       
    
         $scope.sub = [{ id: 1, uom: 'Tam' }, { id: 2, uom: 'Eng' },
                      { id: 3, uom: 'Math' }, { id: 4, uom: 'Science' }];
         $scope.selectedName=$scope.names[0].Name;
         $scope.selectedUom=$scope.sub[0].uom;
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="stud details" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">

     Gender:<select ng-model="selectedName">
            <option ng-repeat="x in names">{{x.Name}}</option>
        </select>


    Subject:<select ng-model="selectedUom">
        <option ng-repeat="x in sub">{{x.uom}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @vinayakvk. Oh.. Have you check my answer?  Are you able to compare my code and yours?

Comment: yes , i run with your code.but i have get this same error.

Comment: List items can't populate this list box